# Installing Ubuntu for the first time on new laptop, wanting to boot only ubuntu not windows

Tags: boot, 18.04

I have a lenovo T495 with no personal files on the computer yet. Is there a way I can install and boot Ubuntu and wipe windows in the first go around, or should I install an older LTS (14.04) and then boot a newer one (18.04)? Also keep in mind I am very new to all this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know your system, but I'd just start with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, or a newer release if you wanted it.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL & thus off-topic, Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is off-topic here as well as supported only via Ubuntu Advantage.  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#0

Comment: Start with Ubuntu 18.04 and select "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" during installation.

Comment: these are the specs for my pc, amd ryzen 7 pro 3700u and integrated radeon vega 10 graphics card. Im not sure what else is relevant.

Comment: @Sharan i checked the install guide and it says "Options related to side-by-side installation or erasing a previous installation are only offered when pre-existing installations are detected." so its sounds like i cant wipe windows until i have a ubuntu already, but i only want to install to the current LTS

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense. How about "Something Else" and creating your own partitions?

Comment: i have windows, but i was thinking that message in the guide was saying the pre-existing installations were ubuntu installations. if im wrong and they mean windows then i think im good to go lol

Comment: yeah, i guess i could do that, im just nervous, guess i could find a decend guide on here or youtube video explaining how to do it

Comment: "Options related to side-by-side installation or erasing a previous installation are only offered when pre-existing installations are detected." that includes windows @Kad135 so go for it!